# array dividing double digit ID into single digit?

Tags: php, mysqli

When a user login, his contacts are shown on index page. In this case the user id is 17 but when i check it using var_dump, it just fetch '1' not '17'. Hence, no data is displayed.

*Index.php*

```
function home()
{
    $results = array();
    $results['pagetitle'] = "Home";

    $homeobj = new data( $_SESSION['user_id'] );
    $results['contacts'] = $homeobj->getcontacts();
    require 'templates/home_form.php';
}
```

*data.class.php*

```
public function __construct( $data = array() )
    {   
        if( isset($data['user_id'])) (int)$this->user_id = $data['user_id'];
        var_dump( $data['user_id'] ); // 1
        var_dump( $data); // 17
        if( isset($data['username']) ) $this->username = $data['username'];
        if( isset($data['password']) ) $this->password = sha1($data['password']);
        if( isset($data['repass']) ) $this->repass = sha1($data['repass']);

    }
```

Comment: `$_SESSION['user_id']` will pass the user_id as a value 17. then why you are accessing with array index `$data['user_id']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not passing array in a constructor

```
$homeobj = new data( $_SESSION['user_id'] ); //here $_SESSION['user_id'] is just an integer id
```

Try instead

```
$data['user_id'] = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$homeobj = new data( $data ); //pass array
```

Comment: No Idea. It should display NULL. May be the value is being set somewhere in your script.